# Is it possible to fix Xbox 360 slim red ring?

Tags: xbox-360, technical-issues

When I turn my Xbox on, the fan spins and the green light comes on, but after 10 seconds the green light goes red. I have got it working before but now its stopped, I can't get it to work anymore.

I have got an Xbox 360 slim 250gb. Is this possible to fix?

Comment: Reference: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xbox_360_technical_problems